# If a stone is dropped from a hot air balloon, is the initial velocity $u=0$, or is it equal to the velocity of the balloon $u=V_{balloon}$?

Tags: kinematics, velocity, inertia

In theory, since the stone acquires the velocity of the balloon, it should go upwards slightly before coming down since it's velocity is equal to that of the balloon (in upward direction). But realistically, does it so the same? Asking from the perspective of an observer on the ground.

Comment: Sure it does. Forget the balloon, and just imagine a stone released at some height $h$ above ground level, with an initial velocity $\vec{u}_0$ upwards. Now it's obvious what happens, right? (Of course, for most practical purposes, $\vec{u}_0$ is negligible.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes absolutely. When a stone is dropped from a hot-air baloon rising up with some velocity, the stone acquires the velocity of the balloon for a brief time after it has been dropped. Remember that this upward velocity is not visible from the point of view of someone standing on the balloon and is only visible to someone on the ground.